# Как выполнять код PHP при наступлении события JavaScript?

Tags: события, php, javascript

Если можно, предложите несколько возможных вариантов. Узнал один

```
onclick="window.location.href='1.php'"
```

Comment: Ajax? или вы о чем?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить php, существует только 2 способа - это открыть url с кодом, будь то клик по ссылке, или как у вас в примере [переход из js](http://pyramidin.narod.ru/clientref13/location.htm), или через [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), так или иначе надо сказать серверу, что вы хотите выполнить php и получить результат. И 2-й -  запустить php скрипт в php консоли, что по факту не имеет здравого смысла. ))